# Laravel, pivot table with childs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, scope, pivot

I'm using 2 models linked by a pivot table, Modules and Clients.

The first one, the modules model, which can have child modules, as the following table structure,

```
| id |...| module_id |
```

where the module_id refers to the parent module.

This model has the following relationships:

```
public function parentModule()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Module::class, 'module_id');
}

public function childModules()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Module::class, 'module_id')
                ->with('childModules')
                ->orderBy('order');
}

public function Clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class, 'client_module', 'module_id', 'client_id');
}

public function scopeBaseModules($query)
{
    return $query->whereNull('module_id');
}
```

So, if i do:

```
Module::BaseModules()->with('childModules')->get()
```

I get all the modules with their respective childs.

```
Module 1
->second level child module X
->->third level child module Y
Module 2
...
```

The Client model its a simple table, with Id and other information, and has the following relationships:

```
public function modules()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class, 'client_module', 'client_id', 'module_id');
}
```

Both tables are linked by a pivot table, client_module, with the structure:

```
| client_id | module_id |
```

So, if i do:

```
Module::BaseModules()
      ->with('childModules')
      ->with('clients')
      ->get()
```

I'll get all the modules, their respective childs, both with the clients linked to them.

Now i need to get that query but returning only the modules, and childs, from a specific client. I've tried the scope:

```
public function scopeClient($query, $client)
{
    return $query->wherePivot('client_id', $client);
}
```

assuming this would filter the query to the client specific id, but no!

Can, someone please, direct me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!

I'll leave here the solution, maybe it becomes useful to someone else.

After a lot of forwards and backs i, finally, managed to get a solution that solves what I've been searching for.

```
Module::BaseModules()
      ->with(['ChildModules' => function($q) use($client) {
         $q->whereHas('clients', function($q) use($client) {
            $q->where('clients.id', $client);
         });
      }])
      ->whereHas('clients', function($q) use($client) {
         $q->where('clients.id', $client);
      })
      ->orderBy('order')
      ->get();
```

This retrieves a recursive collection of the modules filtered by the client.

Examining the SQL created by the query, it doesn't seems like a bad solution.

**** After all, it's is a bad solution... This solution only filters the first level of childs! ****

**Final solution:**

I created a non recursive relationship parent/child.

```
public function childModule()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Module::class, 'parent_id')->orderBy('order');
}
```

Then, to make code easier to read i created two scopes:

```
public function scopeGetByClient($query, $client_id)
{
    return $query->whereHas('clients', function ($q) use ($client_id) {
        $q->where('clients.id', $client_id);
    });
}

public function scopeGetChildsByClient($query, $client_id)
{
    return $query->with(['ChildModule' => function ($q) use ($client_id) {
            $q->whereHas('clients', function ($q) use ($client_id) {
                $q->where('clients.id', $client_id);
            })
            ->getChildsByClient($client_id);
    }]);
}
```

The first scope filters the parent level by client.
The second one gets the first level of childs, filtering them by client, and calls again the same scope, recursively calling all levels off childs.

Finally, to call all this methods:

```
$modules = Module::BaseModules()
        ->getByClient($client->id)
        ->getChildsByClient($client->id)
        ->orderBy('order')
        ->get();
```